# Block typing certain numbers in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use vue.js and have an input with this logic: `onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"` It allows to type only digits from `0` to `9`.
In my vue `data()` I have `limitMin: 20` and would like to include that in my input validation. So if `limitMin: 20`, then I would like to be able to only type in numbers above 20.

```
<input
 type="number"
 :min="this.limitMin"
 onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

Comment: So, what's the issue?

Comment: Use `@keypress="validate" v-model="inputValue"` instead of your onkeypress function. Then, define a value `inputValue: ''` in yout data part of the script part of your component. Then, define a method `validate($event)` in the script part of your component. Move the current code into this method. You can then access the value of the field using `this.inputValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    inputValue: 1,
    limitMin: 20
  },
  methods: {
    validate: function() {
      if (this.inputValue >= this.limitMin) {
        this.inputValue = this.limitMin;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input
    type="number"
    v-model="inputValue"
    @input="validate">
</div>
```

Comment: So I've tried like this, but unfortunately it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/5396asnv/

Comment: Is this what you expect? http://jsfiddle.net/5396asnv/14/ `<input type="number">` only allows numbers anyway..

Comment: The other way around: `if (this.inputValue < this.limitMin` but yes, thank you!